# Fill elements in array of buffers - C

Tags: c, arrays, buffer

I need an array of buffers as follows:
the array has 1000 buffers,
each buffer has 3000 bytes.

Then I need to loop through every buffer to fill it with 3000 bytes,
then I should be able to access each element.

But I have no idea how to do it. Any help?

I am stuck here:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 5000
#define numberOfBuffers 1000

int main(void)
{
    typedef unsigned char byte;
    unsigned int i;
    byte** prom;

    prom = (byte*) calloc(numberOfBuffers, sizeof(byte));

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfBuffers; i++)
        prom[i] = (byte**) calloc(BUFFER_LENGTH, sizeof(byte*));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], especially [ask]. Questions like "Please write the code for me." are considered off-topic. Please show what you have tried. I.e. make as much of a [mcve] as you can, in order to demonstrate that you did spend some effort yourself.

Comment: Have you already tried something or are you just expecting free code from us? Try using `for` loops and `malloc`.

Comment: @Pablo Shiver. Malloc and somebody who needs recommendation to use a for loop for this. 2D static array seems safer, admittedly 3MB in one piece.

Comment: Use a loop that calls `memset()` on each buffer to fill it.

Comment: Can I have some additional lines please? At least a ` return 0;}`at the end of main().

Comment: So far the code looks OK. If you use macros to define constants, you should use all capital letters.  `numberOfBuffers` looks like variable to me and when your code gets big, you may have a problem looking where that damn variable got declared.

Comment: Your code numbers don't match the specification in the text of the question.  Who's confused — you or me?

Comment: @Yunnosch if the dimension are known beforehand and they are not going to change, then you can use a static array, I agree. Seems to me though that the dimensions are not necessarily known and might change even at run time.

Comment: @Pablo: are you sure it looks OK?  The size of the first allocation looks a little undersized to me.

Comment: @Pablo The sizes do change from asking the question to posting the code, yes. ;-) But they are still static at compile time.

Comment: @Yunnosch `int main()` is the one C function not *required* to return a value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler from the code point of view, I don't see anything wrong here. The numbers do not match with the description, sure. But as long as the code consistently uses the values defined in the macros, this looks OK. That's what I meant.

Comment: @WeatherVane You and I know, but why use that exception and knowingly keep a -Wall warning inside? And for an MCVE I definitly insist on the `}`.

Comment: @Pablo: OK — allow me to comment that on most systems, an `unsigned char` (aka `byte`) is not big enough to hold an `unsigned char *` — by a factor of 4 for 32-bit systems and 8 for 64-bit systems.  So, the first allocation is allocating far less memory than is necessary.  'Tis funny because the second allocation is allocating far too _much_ space, by the same factor.

Comment: Note that the standard header `<stdlib.h>` declares `calloc()` and friends.  The non-standard header `<malloc.h>` also does that, but isn't as portable.  It (`<malloc.h>`) defines some extra facilities, but your code isn't making any use of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right, I haven't considered that, I didn't really realize that the `sizeof`s were incorrect. That's why I always use `var = calloc(n, sizeof *var)` which gives me the correct size without having to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allocate your buffers:

```
int i;
unsigned char *b[1000];
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)  b[i] = calloc(sizeof(unsigned char),3000);
```

You can access, for example, the 10th byte of the 5th element as b[4][9]

Comment: thanks Jonathan , let me try , then I will inform you

Comment: Does the code compile warning free with `gcc -Wall`? Looking at the calloc() I doubt it.

Comment: it should be `calloc(1, 3000)`, one element of size 3000.

Comment: Way too complicated. Why not use a 2D array?